# How to save a list of matrices in a file on Sage?

Tags: matrix, text-files, sage

I'm currently working on lattices. To solve some problems, I have to generate a big number of matrices of the same basis. This takes a lot of time. For example, to generate 10'000 bases, I have to launch the code when I go to bed and retrieve the list of basis in the morning. The problem is that I can't do it every day.

So I'd like to save my list of 1000 matrices once for all in a text file. The problem is that when I do it, I get strings.

The matrix list is named BB.

```
with open('yourfile.csv', 'w') as f1:
    writefile = csv.writer(f1)
    writefile.writerows(BB)

import csv
with open('yourfile.csv','rU') as f1:
    data=list( csv.reader(f1) )
```

Do you know how I could find a way to save the matrix list and then, directly recover a list? I'm working on the Sage notebook.

Answer (score 0):

The correct and easiest ways to save and load Sagemath objects via a file are

```py
save(your_list_of_matrix, 'filename.sobj')
```

```py
your_list_of_matrix = load('filename.sobj')
```

Saving Sagemath objects to CSV will need to convert the values into strings and will lose precision.

Refer to the [official document](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/misc/sage/misc/persist.html?highlight=save%20load) for more detail.